# Problem with running flutter with androis configurations on windows machine

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**I've been trying to run my Flutter app in VScode, but the following message appears:**

```
Microsoft Windows [versão 10.0.19042.928]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

C:\projects\tests\fluttertest>flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on Google Nexus 7 in debug mode...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in C:\Users\sophi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

  Using Android SDK: C:\Users\sophi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        17,2s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Also, when I run the flutter doctor in prompt it returns the following message**

```
C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.19042.928], locale pt-BR)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor --android-license
Could not find an option named "android-license".


Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.

C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Warning: File C:\Users\sophi\.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
7 of 7 SDK package licenses not accepted. 100% Computing updates...
Review licenses that have not been accepted (y/N)?
```

I've looked for my repositories.cfg file and it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to SDK Manager and download android 10(if using android studio)
2. Make sure to download JDK Version 1.8
3. Run flutter doctor --android-licenses in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Run : Flutter doctor --andriod-licenses...
Then rund your code back